# Connect to MySQL server for client failed

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm writing an application to upload data for my customer's database. When I tested it on my PC, it works ok but when connecting to the client's database, it has some errors. I'm using this code to connect to MySQL:

```
    def connect_sql(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            passwd=pw,
            port=port,
            database=db,
            user=user,
        )
        return mydb
```

When tried to connect to the database on the client's PC, it shows this error:

```
   1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

I've noticed that this error maybe because different database server version between me and my client. While he uses **5.0.67-community-nt** (which does not support 'utf8mb4') and I use **10.0.21 MariaDB-log**.

Is there any way to fix this error on my site (maybe export .sql file to set the default character set to prevent this error, etc..), or do I need to ask my customer to update his MySQL database's version?

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as following:

```
  def connect_sql(self):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        passwd=pw,
        port=port,
        database=db,
        user=user,
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True
    )
    return mydb
```

Here's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html).